# PhoneGap InAppBrowser not loading pdf

Tags: pdf, cordova

I am using `PhoneGap` InAppBrowser to load `pdf` in my app. It is loading `pdf` in IOS, but there is no location bar shown, and on Android `pdf` is never loaded.
Here is my code to load `pdf`

```
iabRef = window.open('sample.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this counts as an answer, but I believe this is a known bug. It is marked as fixed in the 2.4.0 RC [**here**.](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/46a0c4f330c5815e7b8dfcec94d02e223b2ec258/changelog)

Comment: Yes used 2.4.0 RC but yet no results on Android, not any pdf is loaded  there.

Comment: Best I can recommend then is to file a bug report. Also... what happens if you turn off location=yes? Just to make it simpler?

Comment: Android doesn't have PDF support in it's WebView. In Android's case you need to figure out if it's a PDF or not, and open the PDF with an intent (which should open up an app that can read the PDF).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same with 2.4.0.  I switched to using the `_system` browser in my open call.  It's not ideal, as it opens a browser that simply downloads the file, but at least it works.